# how I can confirm SNS subscription from my app in react?

Tags: aws, react-hooks, sdk

I want to confirm the subscription of my app in react, I'm using aws sdk, there is a method to confirm the subscription but I need a token to do it, I don't know where to get it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SNS.html#confirmSubscription-property

```
var params = {
  Token: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  TopicArn: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
sns.confirmSubscription(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I have seen that the subscription can be confirmed from the AWS console, but I need the subscription confirmation URL to do it and I don't know where to get it.

At this moment I have my application in my local environment and I use grok to publish it on the web.

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)